# Triangle inequality for higher powers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Does an inequality of the following type hold:
Let $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ be any reals and $r$ an integer.

$\left|\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right|^{r}\leq K_{r}\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}\left|x_{i}\right|^{r}$

With $K_{r}$ independent of $n$.

Comment: Let $x_i = 1$ for all $i$. The constant must depend on $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jensen's inequality yields the best possible general constant for any real $r \ge 1$:
$$\left|\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n x_i\right|^r = n^r \left|\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}x_i\right|^r \le n^r \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}|x_i|^r = n^{r - 1} \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n |x_i|^r$$