# Triangle inequality for power of $1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

This may be a simple enough question but is there an equivalent of the triangle inequality when there is a power of $1/2$ and $x$ and $y$ are complex-valued functions. That is
\begin{equation}
|x + y|^{1/2} \leq C\left( |x|^{1/2} + |y|^{1/2}\right)
\end{equation}
where $C$ is a positive constant. I saw a result similar to this at [Triangle inequality for higher powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017374/triangle-inequality-for-higher-powers) but the result there only works for powers greater of equal to $1$.

Comment: $|x+y|^{1/2}\leq (|x|+|y|)^{1/2}\leq |x|^{1/2}+|y|^{1/2}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408177/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/583415/42969

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!